# Converting excel graphs into images

Tags: python, excel

Trying to iterate through an excel sheet, find all of the graph objects and save each object as an image.

I am trying to convert each graph on an excel sheet into an image either png or jpg. I have attached my code below but I keep on getting an attribute error, I am able to iterate through the graphs but I don't know how to save as an image. I would preferably like to just save them as an image instead of recreating the graphs in python.

```
def convert_excel_graph_to_image(file_path, sheet_name, output_file):
    # Load the Excel workbook
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
    
    # Select the worksheet
    worksheet = workbook[sheet_name]
    
    # Access the graph object from the specified cell
    i = 0 
    for chart in worksheet.chart:
        # Create an image object from the graph
        image = Image(chart)
        
        # Save the image as a temporary file
        image_path = "temp_image%d.png" %i
        image.save(image_path)
        
        # Convert the image to the desired format using PIL if needed
        img = PILImage.open(image_path)
        img.save(output_file)
        
        # Close the workbook
        workbook.close()
        
        # Delete the temporary image file
        img.close()
        os.remove(image_path)
        i = i +1
    
#Example
excel_file = "C:/Users/quincoug/Desktop/Quinn Code/PREI Forecasting Tool_Code.xlsm"
sheet_name = "Calc Tool"
output_image = "graph_image.png"

convert_excel_graph_to_image(excel_file, sheet_name, output_image)
```